# MySQL REGEX Query for Special Characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search, select

i have regex query to find out ids which are having same pattern in their text file, considering the word boundary.

```php
$pattern = '[[:<:]]red[[:>:]]';    
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE f_dump REGEXP '$pattern' ");
```

although this works fine , 
but fails in the case of some special words like

`c` , `c++` , `c#`

so , i tried with `like % c# %`

this works but it also fails in cases like ,

example string: `i like working in php,java,c#.`

please help me to solve this problem..

problem is : i need to search for some words in mysql DB , should be matched exactly and should support search for special characters.

p.s. - i am having a innodb DB so , full text search is also not an option for me.(although ver 5.6 supports it , but i am on a older version.)

Comment: Difficult to understand what your expected output is for `f_dump="i like working in php,java,c#"`

Comment: my expected output is that if i search for C# , then it should return true in this case,
if i search for python , it should return false..

Comment: Are these words always comma separated?

Comment: no..this a type of free text , u can find anything in any order , style